Is there a custom function in excel to return closest value below each row to match certain parameters?
This is basically a formatting question where I want to get a certain value in each line of data, instead of where each line above these values corresponds to what the value is.
I am having a hard time wording my question to get an answer but it seems like an offset or match function should do the job somewhere. I've attached a picture with a sample of my data. Essentially I want all of those lines of data in column a with an RTR to return COBX along each row, and I want each row of data in column A with a GPA to return HTXPOS. Is this possible to essentially lookup and return a value who's length or text contains elements that differ and return that different value to every row above it?
Small sample of my excel data in column A

I tried a few different methods to avoid manual entry including a length code and some lookups but they all ended with circular references or manual entry necessity.
EDIT: This is what I want the code to look like for the 500k+ lines of data I am working with. Also worth noting that the number of lines between each unique code, like "COBX" and "HTXPOS" in the example, are different. There is also 500,000 rows of data so any manual entry would need to be avoided such as if(left(A2,3)="RTR") and so forth. If it is worth anything the 4th character in each of the RTR- and GPA- is a - for all 500,000 rows of data, and is never the 4th character in the unique codes such as "COBX" or "HTXPOS".  Desired output of code. All lines above these different values to show different values somewhere in the row.
EDIT #2: Final solution found by @cybernetic.nomad. Works like a charm: =IF(LEN(A2)<13,"",IF(LEN(A3)<13,A3,B3))
Question #2: If there are lines of code with successive unique values like "COBX" and "HTXPOS" in a row such as in example #3 pictured. Is there a way to return all of those unique values instead of just the first 1? Successive lines of unique values where we want to return both or all successive lines to the same cell with a separator between or in a different column, until another 13 character cell appears

Something like IF(LEFT(A1,3)="RTR","COBX",IF(LEFT(A1,3)="GPA","HTXPOS",""))? would work with the provided sample. Unless the actual condition to use is not the first three characters of column A?

=IF(LEN(A2)<13,"",IF(LEN(A3)<13,A3,B3)) may do what you want if the only condition is the length of the strings in column A

Please add a screenshot of your desired output given your posted data.

@cybernetic.nomad I tried something like that but in the end the data is something like 500,000 rows with thousands of unique codes like "COBX" or "HTXPOS" and I would like to avoid manual entry of all of those if possible. I apologize that the snippet of data was unclear.

Works fine for me

One more way using LAMBDA() helper to spill: =LET(α, A2:A14, δ, SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)), φ, δ/ISERR(FIND("-",α)),IFERROR(INDEX(α,IF(ISERR(φ),SORT(SCAN(,SORTBY(φ,δ,-1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISERR(y),x,y)))),"")),""))

@cybernetic.nomad works great for that snippet. Is there a way to include multiple unique codes in a row? For example if HTXPOS and COBX were in lines above and below each other, is there a function to put both out for every 13 length cell above them? For example below, we want to return both COBX and HTXPOS either in the same cell or in column next to each other in same rows. RTR-29-000001
RTR-29-000002
RTR-29-000003
RTR-29-000004
COBX
HTXPOS

@MayukhBhattacharya also works. Is there a way to output multiple unique codes if they are in successive rows. For example if COBX and HTXPOS were in rows A6 and A7. I would like it to be output in either the same column with a comma or space between, or one in each column in that same row.

@Et_33 per post one question. You need to raise a new question for your latest. Also you need to show what you have tried.

There are several ways to do this, depending on exactly what you want for an output, which you haven't shown yet.
In the formula below, I instead of testing for length, I tested for the presence of a hyphen, based on the data set you provided.
No need to hard-code any prefixes or suffixes.
Assuming no version constraints per your tags, try:
A1:A13 = your data
B1: =LET(
    data, A1:A13,
    suffix, FILTER(data, NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND("-", data)))),
    suffixpos, XMATCH(suffix, data),
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(data),
        1,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                OR(r = suffixpos),
                "",
                INDEX(data, XLOOKUP(r, suffixpos, suffixpos, , 1))
            )
        )
    )
)



Here is another way of doing the above, which I have already commented above, it doesn't needs to be filled down as well as, posting it as an alternative method for MS365 Users:


• Formula used in cell B2
=LET(
     α, A2:A14,
     δ, SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),
     φ, SORT(SCAN(,SORTBY(δ/ISERR(FIND("-",α)),-δ), LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISERR(y),x,y)))),
     IF(δ<>φ,INDEX(α,φ,),""))


